# Difference between serialized bytes and ASCII bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization

I ran into a little problem this morning and I'm afraid I need a little help. Every time I want to serialize , let's say, a DataTable for storage in a database and deserialize upon retrieval, I use the following method :

```
public static byte[] DatatableToByteArray(DataTable d)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream, d);
                return stream.GetBuffer();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.WriteError(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This works like a charm and the byte[] returned is easy to store in `blob` or another type of binary database field.

If I want to transfer `byte[]` across a TCP connection, I usually do the following :

```
public bool SendTCP(string server, int port, string message)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient _tcp = new TcpClient();
        _tcp.Connect(server, port);

        Stream stm = _tcp.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(message);

        stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

        //Took out the write back thingy

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write(ex, false);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This also works like a charm and I get my bytes across without a hitch. Now here's my problem. Everything goes south when I mix the two. For example :

```
public void Mixed(string server, int port, string message)
{
    try
    {
        //Create a datatable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("TestColumn", typeof(String));

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["TestColumn"] = "test";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        //Serialize it 
        Byte[] bb = DatatableToByteArray(dt);

        //Send it over the wire
        TcpClient _tcp = new TcpClient();
        _tcp.Connect(server, port);

        Stream stm = _tcp.GetStream();
        //ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        //byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(message);

        stm.Write(bb, 0, bb.Length);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write(ex, false);
    }
}
```

When the other end is deserializing the bytes received, it reports an error :

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Binary stream '0'
>   does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid
>   stream or object version change between serialization and
>   deserialization.    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
>   GCP.Classes.Methods.ByteToDataTable(Byte[] b) in
>   D:\Appz\App1\Classes\Mixed.cs:line x

I took out the `ASCIIEncoding` and tried to send the serialized DataTable directly across the line but the receiving side wouldn't have it. Apparently byte[] isn't byte[]. And I'm curious why. Why is ASCII encoded `byte[]` being re-assembled perfectly and serialized `byte[]` not.

I hope someone can shed a little light on the matter. I highly appreciate any input and thank you in advance.

Comment: You say you want to transfer a `byte[]` across a TCP connection but then show a method that transmits a string. This method, however, is not used when you show the code that "mixes the two". I really don't understand the question here. Can you show the code that *deserializes* on the other end? Since you've posted an exception from that code, we need to see it.

Comment: can you deserialize it back to a valid table, in the SENDER side, just before you transmit it ?

Comment: 1. Why in the world do you serialize a DataTable to a blob to store it in a DB? 2. Encoding in ASCII will not always be enough. Your first non-English customer will break your code with unicode strings.

Comment: @Lasse, I fail to see what you mean. Can you point this out to me. In both methods I send byte[], not a string. byte[] ba in the first example and byte[] bb in the second.

Comment: `public bool SendTCP(string server, int port, string message)` <-- string, but either way, please post your *deserialization* code.

Comment: @Stavm, yes I can. No problem at all.

Comment: @Lasse, That is not the actual sending. The string <message> is just a parameter. The message is converted to byte[]  `byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(message);` and then send across : `stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);`

Comment: Can you please post your *deserialization* code?

Comment: @Fildor. Because then I can encrypt the data (failed to mention that, because it's out of scope of this question) and store it in a single field. And an automated process just grabs the encrypted byte from the DB and sends it across the wire in due time. No need for decrypting and therefore no sensitive data readable in memory or db. I don't rely on DB password for the safety of my data.

Comment: Deserialise after serialization of a DataTable (works perfect): `BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    stream = new MemoryStream(b);
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                    return dt;` .. but not when the byte[] is send across a TCP connection.

Comment: Just a sidenote: `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); stream = new MemoryStream(b);` That's redundant creation of one MemoryStream. You could do `MemoryStream stream; stream = new MemoryStream(b);` or directly `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(b);`

Comment: @Fildor : Well spotted, thank you !